# JQuery: How to search for (key,value) pair in all HTML style attributes and replace value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given some HTML string, Using, JQuery how can I search for all the styles containing for example, font-family:courier

```
<span style='font-family:courier;'>
<p style='font-family:courier;'>
```

and change it to font-family:courier new ?, resulting:

```
<span style='font-family:courier new;'> 2</span>
<p style='font-family:courier new;'>
```

Comment: There are some other questions that answer this, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841850/find-element-by-style-selector-in-jquery), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291605/jquery-select-style-attribute), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625107/is-there-a-style-selector-in-jquery).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your HTML is **exactly** as you've given...

```
$('[style="font-family:courier;"]').css({fontFamily: "courier new"});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/dM8vh/

Comment: I got +1s but this answer seems more robust http://stackoverflow.com/a/22637465/1850421

Comment: It depends if he wants to limit the search to style attributes or include stylesheet values as well. Yours is more specific to the question requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**:

```
$('*').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('font-family') == "courier"
}).css('font-family', 'courier new');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2HT67/)**