# Modify html content using JQuery by style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I am trying to edit html content based on style tags**

Here is the section of html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <span style="color:restest">Testing</span>
    <br>
    <span style="color:restest">Testing Again</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to modify all instances of spans with **style="color:restest"** and add html tags to the contents.

**They should become something like:**

```
<a href="example.com/testing">Testing</a>
<a href="example.com/testing_again">Testing_Again</a>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841850/find-element-by-style-selector-in-jquery

Comment: use $('span').css({color: 'restest'}) simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with [`jQuery#replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```js
$('span[style="color:restest"]').each((i,e) => {
  $(e).replaceWith(`<a href="example.com/${e.innerHTML}">${e.innerHTML}</a>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="color:restest">Testing</span>
<span style="color:restest">Testing Again</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `$('span[style="color:restest"]')`

Comment: @SethMcClaine reason being that i prefer vanilla js over jquery whenever i can use it. However i see  your point and i have updated the answer.

Comment: I agree, but tend to try to stick with one tech instead of jumping back and forth.  Gave you an up though :-)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the help!