# cy.get div that hasn't got a display: none on it

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

I'm working on some poor code, that someone else has written. I'm trying to write some tests for the functionality, before we're changing it, so we can ensure it all works, after the feature-changes.

I have 8 siblings divs like this:

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- Child-1 --> 
  <div class="child-group child-1" style=""> <!-- Notice empty style-tag -->
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="go-to-child-group-1">Child-group-1</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-2">Child-group-2</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-3">Child-group-3</button>
      ... <!-- Leaving out all the buttons for readability -->
      <button class="go-to-child-group-8">Child-group-8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content1 content1 content1</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Child-2 -->
  <div class="child-group child-2" style="display: none"> <!-- Notice display none -->
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="go-to-child-group-1">Child-group-1</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-2">Child-group-2</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-3">Child-group-3</button>
      ... <!-- Leaving out all the buttons for readability -->
      <button class="go-to-child-group-8">Child-group-8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content2 content2 content2</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Child-3 -->
  <div class="child-group child-3" style="display: none"> <!-- Notice display none -->
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="go-to-child-group-1">Child-group-1</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-2">Child-group-2</button>
      <button class="go-to-child-group-3">Child-group-3</button>
      ... <!-- Leaving out all the buttons for readability -->
      <button class="go-to-child-group-8">Child-group-8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content3 content3 content3</div>
  </div>

  <!-- 
  Etc. etc. etc.
  for group Child-4, Child-5, Child-6, Child-7 and Child-8
  -->

</div>
```

When you click one of the buttons, it sets `display: none` on the active group - and removes `display: none` from the child-group that needs to become visible.

I'm trying to write a test, that first activates a certain child-group (by clicking the the button to make it visible) and afterwards checks the content is correct.

But when I do this:

```javascript
cy.get( ".child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2" ).click();
```

Then my test fails with this error:

> cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 8 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.

It's obviously crap, that all the buttons are loaded on each element. But we can't change that until further down the line.

**How do I select only the `.child-group` that *doesn't* have `display: none` set on it?**

---

### Solution attempt 1: Select by style

I found this post on [how to select by style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841881). But since I'm trying to select the one *without* the style, that makes this more difficult.

I tried this:

```
cy.get( ".child-group[style*='display: block'] .buttons .go-to-child-group-2" ).click();
```

But that doesn't work. And when I inspect the element without the `display: none`, then I can find no `display`-style on it. And I could also read that [display didn't have any default value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

---

### Solution attempt 2: Make `cy.get(...)` disregard all non-visible elements.

I found a bit about [Interacting with Elements](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements), but it didn't tell me how I could pass that option the my `cy.get`-function.

I also checked [the documentation for cy.get](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get), but couldn't find anything either.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Simply click all the buttons (poor)

I could do what it says and click all the buttons, by calling the click-function like this:

```
cy.get( ".child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2" ).click( {multiple: true, force: true});
```

This works, but I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`:not()` pseudo selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```js
cy.get('.child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2:not([style="display: none"])')
```

I guess it's also worth trying this, but not sure if the empty string will throw it

```js
cy.get('.child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2[style=""]')
```

Comment: I couldn't get the `:not`-command to work. But your seconds suggestion worked! `cy.get('.child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2[style=""]')`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```js
cy.get('.child-group .buttons .go-to-child-group-2')
  .filter(':visible') // filter only visible elements
```

[Here is a simple example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/displayNone.md)

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I tried this a little bit. But I'm not sure if I can simply put a `.then( (elements) => { ... } );` after the filter and click the filtered elements. When I played with it, I didn't get it to work. And your suggestion shows how to assert something, with the filtered results, but not how to interact with it.

Comment: It would help out more with the overall picture if you could provide the code on how the styling is updated for the butotns.